# asp.net + javascript passing argument to button click

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a javascript script like this below which the 'args' contain a string that I want to pass it to my 'btnLoadGridFrTrans_VouHist' button click. Can someone please advice. Thanks.

```
function frmIframeChild_VouHist(args)

{            

 var btn = document.getElementById('<%=btnLoadGridFrTrans_VouHist.ClientID%>');            

 if (btn) btn.click();       

 }

  Protected Sub btnLoadGridFrTrans_VouHist_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnLoadGridFrTrans_VouHist.Click
        LoadGrid()
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me.Page, Me.GetType(), "Test", "$('#uidivCardInfo').css('display','inline');$('#divNewMembershipTypeIssuance').css('display','none');$('#divCard_Process').css('display','inline');ShowHide('Voucher_History','" + URLEncryption(CardNo) + "','success#tabs_Used');", True)
  End Sub
```

Comment: Could you provide your HTML or ASPX button control code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a hidden field (containing the value of args) to the document just before submitting it. The click event could read the value of the hidden field via `Request.Form["`fieldName`"]`.

Comment: Thanks, I thought of hiddenfield but was wondering if there's a way to do without it.